# advanced search in Google apps script ContactsApp

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I get contact by email in certain group? In other words - how to combine those two (or more) queries:

```
ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress(...);
ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we can combine both the queries. But to achieve the mentioned criteria, you can get the contacts by group first and verify them against the email address you wanted to get contacts for.

```
var grpContacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(...);
 for (var i = 0; i < grpContacts.length; i++) {
insert code to verify with the email address

}
```

Hope that helps!